# Special Function Keys are not working in Ubuntu 14.0.4.2 LTS

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, brightness, function-keys

Volume (+/-/Mute), Brightness (up/down), Disable Webcam, Mute Microphone and Projector Function keys are not working (when used through laptop keyboard) but Next, Pause/Play and Previous keys are working perfectly fine.

However, the volume/Brightness functions are working perfectly fine from an external USB connected keyboard.

I tried `gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down` as suggested in one of the Ubuntu Forum threads. But this didn't help much.

This issue still exists after resetting all Keys through `gsettings`.

I even tried using `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up "XF86AudioRaiseVolume"`.

There is no issue as such with the Keyboard since the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys associated with each key is working perfectly fine.

None of them are fixing this issue. Can you please help me get this fixed ?